# Testing REST client return handshake_failure when call https

Tags: rest, ssl, https, java-8, tls1.2

I'm trying to call a `REST API` for this [end point URL](https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/regionalbloc/usan). But I'm getting this exception

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

I have already added the `JCE` and installed the certificate in the Java keystore.

I'm using `Java 8` and part of my code looks like this:

```
 Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
 WebTarget target = client.target(END_POINT);
 Invocation.Builder invocationBuilde = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
 Response response = invocationBuilder.get();
 String s = response.readEntity(String.class);
 System.out.println(s)
```

In addition to this I activated the debug mode `-Djavax.net.debug=all` and this is all the negotiation:
[Negotiation REST API](https://pastebin.com/kUew2qr0)

Comment: What libraries do you use? What do you use behind `Client`, `WebTarget`?

Comment: JAX-RS: Java API for RESTful Web Services.

Comment: It depends from given implementation but take a look on this page: http://adambien.blog/roller/abien/entry/jax_rs_client_javax_net

Comment: Yes, I already tried to do it that way

Comment: That's strange. I checked this code and it works for me for `HTTP` and `HTTPS` `URL`-es. I use `javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.1.1` and `org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.26-b03` libraries.

Comment: Can you show me your example?

Comment: I just used your's code. Added imports from `javax.ws.rs.client.*` and `javax.ws.rs.core.*` packages and it works for me. Prints something like `[{"name":"Argentina","topLevelDomain":[".ar"],"alpha2Code":"AR"....`